# How to show only processes which consume more than certain % of memory using htop

Tags: command-line, process, htop

Is there a way to show the processes using htop which consume say > 10% or CPU? I am a bit overwhelmed by the huge swaths of information.

Comment: Your question says `top` but the tag says `htop`. Which one is it now?

Comment: Now it says stop, so please update your question

Comment: @Panki. I think it got auto corrected. I meant htop

Comment: You can use F6 to sort by CPU usage (and ignore the later entries). You can also start it with `-d 15` to only have it refresh every 15 seconds as otherwise your entires are jumping around all the time.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a way to *only* show those processes with over 10% memory used, but you can sort by the percent of memory or CPU hitting `F6` and selecting `PERCENT_MEM` or `PERCENT_CPU`. You could make your terminal window smaller to only see the top few.

Answer (score 1):

`top -o %MEM` will open `top` and automatically sort by highest memory usage to lowest.